# Why running an asynchronous coroutine does not yield control back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a sample code:

```
import asyncio

import time

async def asyncsleep(number):
    time.sleep(number)

async def do_one():
    await asyncsleep(1)
    print("one 1")
    await asyncsleep(1)
    print("one 2")
    await asyncsleep(1)
    print("one 3")

async def do_two():
    await asyncsleep(1)
    print("two 1")
    await asyncsleep(1)
    print("two 2")
    await asyncsleep(1)
    print("two 3")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([
    do_one(),
    do_two()
]))
loop.close()
```

This code is expected to have the two functions run parallel. I mean the output of both should come at the same time. But it is not happening. The reason is that I have implemented an sleep function myself `asyncsleep`. If I use `asyncio.sleep` instead of it, everything works fine.

```
import asyncio

import time

async def asyncsleep(number):
    time.sleep(number)

async def do_one():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("one 1")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("one 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("one 3")

async def do_two():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("two 1")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("two 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("two 3")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([
    do_one(),
    do_two()
]))
loop.close()
```

I also have looked up the signature of `asyncio.sleep` function:

```
@coroutine
def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay == 0:
        yield
        return result

    if loop is None:
        loop = events.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    h = future._loop.call_later(delay,
                                futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                                future, result)
    try:
        return (yield from future)
    finally:
        h.cancel()
```

What the `asyncio.sleep` function has that my implemented `asyncsleep` function does not have? They are both coroutines, Why are they behaving differently?

Comment: `time.sleep` is synchronous. If `time.sleep` worked like that, `asyncio.sleep` wouldn't exist.

Comment: @user2357112 Isn't the reason of `asyncio` to wrap synchronous into asynchronous?

Comment: Sticking a synchronous call in an async function doesn't make it asynchronous.

Comment: The point of asyncio is to make I/O calls non-blocking. CPU-bound tasks (e.g., `time.sleep`) do not see such benefits.

Comment: The reason for asyncio is avoiding callback hell by allowing async functions to automatically suspend when they need the result of a future that is not yet ready (that's what `await` does). Just like in JavaScript, this prohibits the use of blocking calls in async functions.

Comment: @dirn: `time.sleep` isn't CPU-bound.

Comment: True, it's not CPU-bound, but it's *blocking*, and that's what matters.

Comment: If you absolutely must use blocking calls, wrap them in `run_in_executor`, as in `await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, number)`. That will offload the blocking call to a thread pool and relinquish control to the event loop until it completes.

Comment: Yeah, I worded that poorly. The point, though, is that asyncio is for asynchronous I/O.

Comment: @user4815162342 Every function call is blocking. How to make a non cpu bound task / function non-blocking? (without using threads). Is it possible? How? (The question is valid because we have database calls, we have sockets, they are not cpu bound but are blocking but we can use them non-blocking fashion in python, How are they implemented?)

Comment: @TechJS Every function call is blocking in the technical sense (it blocks the calling thread until the function returns or raises), but in this context a distinction is made between functions like `list.append` that do their work in a small amount of time, and `time.sleep` or `sock.recv`, which can block the thread indefinitely. The solution is not to call such functions, and use their async variants instead. This is what asyncio does, with some additional magic to suspend the coroutine when the condition it is awaiting (such as asyncio.sleep) is not yet ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do asynchronous things, you do not have continiuous flow. There is an [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#event-loop), that has a pool of [tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object) and switches between them: when the current task `await`s, the loop passes the control to one of the other tasks in the pool.

[time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future), as gracefully stated in comments by @user2357112, is synchronous, it just blocks the execution for some time, not giving the opportunity to proceed to a different coroutine.

So, what `asyncio.sleep` has and your `asyncsleep` has not:

- It creates a new [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) (a special object representing the result of a task that is not *yet* completed)
- That new task does nothing, but takes specified time
- So the new future will yield the `result` when the time comes
- That task helps to block a flow in which the `asyncio.sleep` was awaited but does not block the other tasks.

Feel the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Async is not threads.  Async code does not give up control until it hits an await or the function completes.  Your sleep function doesn't give up control so:

The asyncio loop is running and do_one and do_two are scheduled.  The loop chooses to run do_one and because you don't yield or await your code doesn't return to the loop until the function completes.